# VB.net Office VSTO Addin WorkbookBeforeSave does not have signature compatible

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, add-in

I was trying to start with VSTO Addin for Office and I translated an example Microsoft published in their [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022) . But I always receive this error when I implemented the `WorkbookBeforeSave` event:

`Method 'Application_WorkbookBeforeSave' cannot handle event 'WorkbookBeforeSave' because they do not have a compatible signature`

I searched in google and it looks the signature is ok. I tried this examples in C# and it worked fine.

this is the code I have:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ThisAddIn
  
  Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    AddHandler Application.WorkbookBeforeSave, New Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(AddressOf Application_WorkbookBeforeSave)
  End Sub

  Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

  End Sub

Sub Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(wb As Workbook, SaveUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.WorkbookBeforeSave(
    Dim activeworksheet As Worksheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    Dim firstRow As Range = activeworksheet.get_range("A1")

    firstRow.EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown)
    Dim newFirstRow As Range = activeworksheet.get_tange("A1")
    newFirstRow.Value2 = "This text was added by using code"

  End Sub
End Class
```

The error is the line that has "(AddressOf Application_WorkbookBeforeSave)"
Could somebody help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was my mistake. The mistake was in the declaration :

```
Sub Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(wb As Workbook, SaveUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.WorkbookBeforeSave
```

The argument `Cancel as Boolean` should be `By Ref Cancel as Boolean`